# How can i regroup some columns in django?

Tags: django

Here is my **view** :

```
clients = models.Client.objects.all()
sellin = models.Sellinvoice.objects.filter(client_id__in = clients)
```

It is my **template**:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>ClientName</th>
    <th>Price</th>
 </tr>
 {% regroup sellin by client.name as list %}
 {% for cl in list %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{ cl.grouper }}</td>
    <td>{{ cl.client.price }}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Result is:**

| ClientName | Price | (if user have two invoice this column added automatically) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john doe | 30000 | 30000 (problem) |
| maria | 12000 |  |
| david | 43000 |  |

**Some user have two invoice and I can regroup `ClientName` but how can regroup Prices?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding new loop and `forloop.first` element to if statement:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th>ClientName</th>
    <th>Price</th>
 </tr>
 {% regroup sellin by client.name as list %}
 {% for cl in list %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{ cl.grouper }}</td>
    {% for obj in cl.list %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <td>{{ obj.client.price }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now result is :

| ClientName | Price |
| --- | --- |
| john doe | 30000 |
| maria | 12000 |
| david | 43000 |